# Uncountable components

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

In Principles and  Techniques of Applied Mathematics by Bernard Friedman, the author writes

> For example, all functions $f(t)$ continuous on the interval $0 < t < 1$ form
>   a linear vector space with the function $f(t)$ considered as a vector. The
>   components of the vector would be the values of the function at different
>   points of the interval.

This space has uncountable components. My question is whether vector spaces with uncountable components actually have much use in functional analysis.

Comment: Clearly $C[0,1]$ is used widely in functional analysis.

Comment: I would say that there would be no Functional Analysis without this.

Comment: The notion of "uncountable components" may seem outlandish, but it is essentially about the size of a *basis* for the vector space being uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

**They are the fundamental object of functional analysis**

Functional analysis is about Banach spaces. That is to say vector spaces equipped with a norm that makes them complete. Specifically FA is about infinite-dimensional spaces, because if the space is finite-dimensional everything is already covered by bog-standard linear algebra.

The simplest example of a Banach space is $B[0,1]$: The space of bounded functions $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ with the $\sup$ norm. For an element $f \in B[0,1]$ you might refer to the values $f(x)$ as the "components" of $f$. You might define the "$x$-th component function" to be $1$ at $x$ and zero elsewhere. Then $f$ can be expressed as an (infinite?) linear combination of component functions.

This approach cannot be done for more exotic spaces. Even considering the subspace of continuous functions $C[0,1] \subset B[0,1]$ we cannot use the same component functions because they are not continuous.

In general all we can talk about is the dimension of a space. If the dimension is infinite is it equal to $|\mathbb N|$, $|\mathbb R|$ or something bigger? The space does not have a special set of "coordinate functions". It does admit what we call a **Hamel basis**. But it admits many different Hamel bases and none is more natural than any other.

But we do have a theorem:

> **Theorem:** The dimension of every Banach space is either finite or uncountable.

So the answer to your question is yes.

**Note:** The above "coordinate functions" for $B[0,1]$ do not form a Hamel basis.